# Cannot flag nodes and comments automatically

Tags: 8, entities, flags

I created a code to automatically flag nodes and comments. When I put only the code to flag the nodes, it works. But when I add the code to flag the comments it doesn't work anymore.

Which code should I use ?

```
<?php

function admin_task_notify_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  // Flag node.
  if (in_array($entity->bundle(), ['annonce', 'article', 'demande', 'discussion', 'evenement', 'itineraire', 'recette'])) {
    $flag_id = 'report_node';

    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

    $flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);
  }

  // Flag comment.
  if (in_array($entity->bundle(), ['annonce', 'article', 'demande', 'discussion', 'evenement', 'itineraire', 'recette', 'produit', 'service'])) {
    $flag_id = 'report_comment';

    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

    $flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);
  }

}
```

Comment: You check for $entity->bundle(), but remember that $entity can be a node or a comment. The part for the comment will not work because I am quite sure that when your second if statement is true YOU expect $entity to be a comment but it is a node - just nodes have bundles, comments do not have these configurable bundles. Your flag with id 'report_comment' will surely expect the entity to be a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. What should be the code to correct the problem? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flag new user accounts or updated accounts?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296833/how-do-i-flag-new-user-accounts-or-updated-accounts)

Comment: @Neograph734 The questions are on different entity for which I am blocked

Comment: I guess you have to check `$entity->getEntityTypeId()` instead of bundle. This code will return the entity type (node, comment).

Comment: @sanzante I found the solution but I still have an error https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296773/how-do-i-flag-the-update-store-automatically/296786?noredirect=1#comment376124_296786

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in the following way so that it works as you expect:

```
  // Flag comment.
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'comment') {
    $flag_id = 'report_comment';

    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

    $flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your code is going to flag any kind of comment I think. How can I specify the types of comments to be flagged? For example if I have the machine name "page", "article", "reciepe". I only want to flag the "page" and "reciepe" comment type.

Comment: I tested your code but it does not flag the comment

Comment: You need to get the commented node (I do not know how the comment entity brings that to you) and check against the bundle of the commented node - not the comment itself. When the code does not flag your comment there might be some other issue. Is the flag id correct? Is the flag report_comment correctly configured?

Comment: Yes the flag is correct, but it doesn't work. I just tested with stores (Commerce module) and it doesn't work. https://pastebin.com/ieRMuH2Y

Comment: Any logs? Any error messages? You write you tried it now with stores so you use another code as you wrote here?! As the same code works with nodes I think that there is something else mis-configured but it may not be the code posted here

Comment: I redid my code but only the nodes work. There is a big problem with this code https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/blob/main/admin_task_notify.module

Comment: When I update a comment, I have this error in my logs `Error : Call to undefined method Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment::getType() dans admin_task_notify_comment_update() (/var/www/www-example-com/web/modules/custom/admin_task_notify/admin_task_notify.module ligne 84)`