# How do I flag the update store automatically?

Tags: 8, commerce, flags

I created a flag to flag the stores. I want when a user updates a store, the store is automatically flagged. The code below does not work and there is no error message.

I don't want to use the Rules module.

How do I flag the update store automatically?

```
use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Flag store.
 */
function admin_task_notify_commerce_store_update(Store $commerce_store) {

    $flag_id = 'report_store';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store);
  
}
```

Comment: Your codes matches the example from the [FlagServiceInterface](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/8.x-4.x/src/FlagServiceInterface.php#L186) so that should work. Did you test if the function `admin_task_notify_entity_update()` is being called?

Comment: @Neograph734 I updated the code for the question. What exactly should I put on ?

Comment: If you get no error and no result, are you sure that the function (I suppose hook_entity_update for custom module admin_tasks_notify) is called? Have you tested it with some other code to see if that works? Did you clear the cache? It might be unrelated to flag. (Besides a lot of those use statements are not needed for this code)

Comment: @Neograph734 I don't know, because I'm new to the custom module. My module is here: https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/tree/main There are only 2 files and I just want to flag the created or updated entity.

Comment: The flag part seems fine, so it must be something else. If you cannot answer my questions, I cannot help you.

Comment: @Neograph734 I don't know what to answer because there is no error. Yes I emptied the cache with DRUSH CR. In the module link of my previous comment, did he add the USE lines?

Comment: That is why I recommend you to try something else within the function. Create a node, display a message, anything other than flag. That would allow you to deduct whether it is the flag code or the custom module.

Comment: @Neograph734 If only do the following code, it works for the node. But if I add other entities, it doesn't work anymore https://pastebin.com/BqXTyQ1q

Comment: @Neograph734 I had done this module a long time ago. It creates a message when an entity is created. But I can't seem to do this with my Flag module. https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3072485/-/blob/master/user_activity_stream.module

Comment: @Neograph734 The following code works for nodes https://pastebin.com/Y0tEui3s but how to specify that the code must be applied only for the nodes of type "article" and "advertisement" ?

Comment: @Neograph734 I updated my question, I don't know if my code is good practice. Only the nodes are flagged automatically. The rest doesn't work and there are no errors in the logs. I do not understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flag new user accounts or updated accounts?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296833/how-do-i-flag-new-user-accounts-or-updated-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok, and you confirm it works for nodes. Then I can only guess that the used flag_ids are wrong, the flag is not enabled for the given entity, or the user does not have permission to place the flag .

Comment: Everything is OK, the machine names are correct and the permissions too. The problem comes from my module. Only the nodes work. If I create a group, the user is flagged, why? https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/blob/main/admin_task_notify.module

Comment: It works for updating stores, but it doesn't work for creating stores. I want to be flagged automatically for creating and updating stores.

Comment: That was never part of the question. Please do not use comments for follow up questions. But you might try hook_entity_insert().

Comment: I have the same error as for the comments `
Message Error : Call to undefined method Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store::getType() dans admin_task_notify_commerce_store_insert() (/var/www/www-example-com/web/modules/custom/admin_task_notify/admin_task_notify.module ligne 33)` Here is my code https://pastebin.com/gqPAHzKA

Comment: You'll need to learn some basic debugging. Apparently stores do not have the getType() method, so you'll need something else. Dig into commerce store/src/entity/Store.php and see what you can use.

Comment: ok thanks, i will look for it. My code must it be in 2 part "update" and "insert"? how the previous link

Comment: I have this module but how to insert it in the module of my question with several types of store https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170717/-/blob/main/commerce_marketplace_premium_merchant.module

Comment: I added the "use" with the type. But I don't know how to use this in my code: https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/blob/main/admin_task_notify.module

Comment: Great, I finished my code and it works https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711/-/blob/main/admin_task_notify.module But I have an error because if I create an entity and modify it, it cannot be flagged twice. How to solve this problem ? And I have a question, why the creation and the update of the nodes works with "update" while for the other entities it is necessary to use "insert" and "update" ?

Comment: ` Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException : The user has already flagged the entity with the flag. dans Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (ligne 846 de /var/www/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).` and `LogicException : The user has already flagged the entity with the flag. dans Drupal\flag\FlagService->flag() (ligne 253 de /var/www/www-example-com/web/modules/contrib/flag/src/FlagService.php).
`