# How do I flag new user accounts or updated accounts?

Tags: 8, users, flags

I created a custom module to automatically flag new user accounts and updated accounts. When I create a new user or update an existing account, it is not automatically flagged and there is no error message in the log.

How do I flag new user accounts or updated accounts?

This is the code I am using in the custom module.

```php
use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Implements hook_user_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_user_update(User $account) {
  $flag_id = 'moderate_user';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $flag_service->flag($flag, $account, $user_admin);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113198/discussion-on-question-by-sdfff-how-do-i-flag-new-user-accounts-or-updated-accou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function admin_task_notify_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_form') { // check is user form
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'admin_task_notify_flag_user'; // adds custom handler
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_flag_user(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) { // the custom handler
  $flag_id = 'moderate_user';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $user_to_flag_uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');
  $user_to_flag = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user_to_flag_uid);
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag, $user_admin); // get flag status
  $is_admin = $user_to_flag->hasRole('administrator');
  if (!$flag_status && !$is_admin) { // if flag not TRUE, is FALSE, not flagged and user is not admin
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $user_to_flag, $user_admin);
  }
}
```